# A 'Kinda' Normal Distribution Over the Unit Interval? (the ladybug won't die)

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, maximum-likelihood

Update: I added the stochastic-processes tag.

For my non-theoretical computer model/application, I'm trying to approximate a Bernoulli random variable. So we are 'watching the ladybug' to get a real-time estimate of the probability as each observation is processed.

The application uses an $\alpha$ of $\text{1%}$. This is a filtering parameter - we allow for the fact that the Bernoulli distribution itself can change over time. If things (strategic adaptions) changed quickly, an $\alpha = \text{10%}$ might work better - we 'open up the filter' to place more value in the current reading.

---

Let $\alpha = 0.01$.

A ladybug is walking on the open unit interval $(0,1)$. She starts at the midpoint $\frac{1}{2}$. Every minute she makes a move to either the right (a larger number) or to the left (a smaller number).

The ladybug makes the move by flipping a coin.

If the coin comes up heads and she is at position $x$, she move to the right to the number

$\tag 1 x  + \alpha \, (1 - x) = (1 - \alpha)\,x + \alpha$

If the coin comes up tails and she is at position $x$, she move to the left to the number

$\tag 2 (1  - \alpha) \, x$

> If the ladybug does this for many weeks, is there a continuous random
>   variable that statisticians use to estimate probabilities that the
>   ladybug is in some sub-interval?

Note: I am just curious about this and would expect any answer to be a bit esoteric from my perspective. For example, it might involve [Beta distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), something that I've never studied.

Comment: The following link regarding generalized central limit theorems seems relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/89254/clt-can-be-used-for-weighted-sum-of-different-bernoulli-variables

Comment: If $X$ is a random variable with the limiting distribution and $f(r) = E[e^{rX}]$ then $f(r)=f((1-\alpha)r)g(r)$ where $g(r) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{r\alpha} +1)$.

Comment: The central limit theorem here is a red herring: the process has a non-gaussian limit distribution; there is no $\sqrt{\cdot}$ rescaling and no cancellation as one would expect in a CLT situation.  Instead, a few terms dominate over the others, which is precisely what the Feller-Lindeberg conditions are designed to rule out.

Answer (score 4):

As Kimchi Lover notes in comments below, this is quite a complex problem related to a specially structured random walk. The answer below gives a “one shot” look at it, but is incomplete.

---

I doubt that this follows any nice distribution exactly. Let $X_0$ be the initial position of the ladybug (*i.e.* $X_0=1/2$). Then the next position of the ladybug, $X_1$, is given by
$$ X_1=(1-\alpha)X_0+\alpha{S_0},$$
where $S_0$ is a [Bernoulli random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with mean $p$ ($p=1/2$ in your example). Note that $X_1$ is now a random variable. Repeating in this manner, we can derive an expression for $X_{n+1}$ for arbitrary $n$...
$$ X_{n+1}=(1-\alpha)^{n+1}X_0+\alpha\sum_{k=0}^n(1-\alpha)^kS_{n-k}.$$
This is just a constant plus a linear combination of Bernoulli random variables. It may be possible to work out the CDF of $X_n$ in closed form, but in general, a linear combination of Bernoulli random variables doesn't exactly follow any nice distribution.

However, this is well approximated with a normal distribution (*cf.* the central limit theorem) with mean $p$ and variance
$$ \frac{p(1-p)\alpha^2}{1-(1-\alpha)^2} $$
(I obtained these expressions by computing the variance of $X_n$ above and taking the limit as $n\to\infty$). We can see that this approximation is rather poor for small $n$ (say, $n=10$):

[image: only ten samples gives a poor fit]

but looks better as $n\to\infty$ (approximated here by $n=5000$):

[image: looks great as the CLT kicks in.]

(these plots are for $p=1/2$ and $X_0=1/2$, per the question).

However, as brought up in the comments, this normal approximation seems to hold only when $\alpha\ll1$ (so that $\sigma^2$ is small). Here's a similar plot to the above, this time with $\alpha=1/2$:

[image: poor approximation!]

More study needed!

Comment: See section 2 of https://web.calpoly.edu/~kmorriso/Research/RandomWalks.pdf , where this walk is called the "geometric random walk".  Things are subtler than this answer suggests.

Comment: @kimchilover Ah that’s very interesting. I was trying to work on the case for $\alpha=1/k$ for integral $k$ but didn’t complete it. I’ll update my answer a bit. Thanks for the insight

Comment: @kimchilover : How is this related to the geometric random walk given in your link?  It seems that walk  converges to a value, while this one does not (this one keeps jumping).  The step sizes there are deterministic while these are not.

Comment: What is $\alpha$ in the above plots?  Is it such that the variance $\sigma^2$ is very small?  The plots are  interesting but there must be some discrepancy since Gaussian $N(p, \sigma^2)$ variables are not contained in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Michael $\alpha=0.01$ per the OP. And I definitely agree re: the discrepancy. Haven't had a chance to think about the theory (just ran some tests to see how it looked). Was thinking it might be confirmed with the Lyapunov CLT.

Comment: I see, so with $p=1/2, \alpha =0.01$ then $\sigma^2\approx 0.001256281$, which is perhaps small enough for most of the probability to be contained in $[0,1]$. Perhaps some non-obvious scaling or some "truncated form" of CLT is needed?

Comment: @Michael I was thinking about some kind of scaling, but haven't considered it carefully. I can look at larger $\alpha$ values later to see, hopefully

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90268/discussion-between-david-m-and-michael).